# Facebook scraper cant get content of URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook **scraper** cannot load URL content (and therefore any OG meta data) on any website running our system, for example: http://www.datour.cz - gives empty result, see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.datour.cz%2F

We tried disabling GZIP compression, but it didn't help.

Comment: Seems to be working fine? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.datour.cz%2F

Comment: @CBroe no, those are only cached results, when you try to click the link next to Scraped URL down on page, it returns blank page

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ shows “errors that must be fixed” - so do that first; you can not expect the cache to update while those are still present.

Comment: @CBroe I strongly believe, that those errors are reported because it can't scrap HTML of that page. When you try to scrap following URL: http://www.datour.cz/cerna-hora/sutomore/hotel-korali-all-inclusive-club-dotovane-pobyty-50-428308 og:title is present and is string, but it still reports that og:title is missing

Comment: Well then go check your server logs, and see if request by the FB scraper reach it, and if so how they are answered.